# How to write more that one statement in the same SPROC

Tags: t-sql

Since i don't have the **ModuleID**, I'd like to get from the Modules table first using the **ModuleName**.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spEditTask
@ID                     int,
@ModuleName             varchar(50), 
@Task                   varchar(50), 
@ListOfDevelopers       varchar(50),
@StartDate              date, 
@PlannedEndDate         date, 
@EstimatedEndDate       date, 
@Status                 varchar(50),
@Comments               varchar(500),
@LastAction             varchar(50),
@Started                 bit
AS
BEGIN 

  DECLARE @ModuleID int; 
  SET @ModuleID = 
  (SELECT ModuleID 
  FROM Modules
  WHERE ModuleName = @ModuleName); 
  GO

  UPDATE DTasks
SET ModuleID = @ModuleID, 
    Task = @Task, 
    ListOfDevelopers = @ListOfDevelopers, 
    StartDate = @StartDate, 
    PlannedEndDate = @PlannedEndDate, 
    EstimatedEndDate = @EstimatedEndDate, 
    Status = @Status, 
    Comments = @Comments, 
    LastAction = @LastAction,
    Started  = @Started,
    LastUpdated = GETDATE() 
WHERE ID  = @ID
GO
END
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: "GO" is not a T-SQL statement.  It's a client batch separator.  It does not belong in stored procedures.

Comment: I removed it now it worked. I have to fix some others problems too. But that one I fixed the last. Now it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your lines in `begin` and `end`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spEditTask 
@ID                     int, 
@ModuleName             int, 
@Task           varchar(50) 
as 
begin     
    DECLARE @ModuleID int;  

    SELECT @ModuleID = ModuleID  
    FROM Modules 
    WHERE ModuleName = @ModuleName  

    UPDATE DTasks 
    SET   ModuleID = @ModuleID,  
      Task = @Task,  
    WHERE ID   = @ID 
end
```

although you could use just a single line

```
UPDATE DTasks
SET
   ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID,
   Task = @task
FROM DTasks cross join Modules
WHERE DTasks.ID = @ID
AND Modules.ModuleName = @ModuleName
```

Comment: Actually that is not correct. The `begin` and `end` is not needed.

Comment: I used you the second technic you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the `as` keyword, and parentheses around the select expression:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spEditTask
@ID                     int,
@ModuleName             int,
@Task           varchar(50)
AS

DECLARE @ModuleID int; 

SET @ModuleID =
(SELECT ModuleID 
FROM Modules
WHERE ModuleName = @ModuleName)

UPDATE DTasks
SET   ModuleID = @ModuleID, 
      Task = @Task, 
WHERE ID   = @ID
```

Comment: I just add AS keyword but I have the same problem. The error is: The operation could not be completed. hard to tell what's the problem. I've also correct the @ModuleName, which is varchar not an int. Yes I added paranthesis as well.

Comment: @Richard77: The parentheses around the select expression also.

Comment: Now you have the whole Sproc.

Comment: @Richard77: Remove the `go` keywords. It's a batch separator in Management Studio, which means that the `update` is not part of the procedure. The `begin` and `end` around the code is optional.